# How to make a run button (GML)

Tags: gml

I'm making a game in game maker and I've looked every where, but all the answers are no help. I've tried for about an hour to no avail. If some one could help that would be great (I'm new to programming).

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is not descriptive enough if you're trying to create something like a start button;

1. create a sprite ("START")
2. make an object for that sprite
3. create two rooms (mainmenu, level1)
4. add a click event to  obj_start
5. use this code: `room_goto(room_level1);`
6. place start object to the room_mainmenu

but if you're trying to make a pause-start type of run button you can either use the complicated way(google;gml pause) or cheat with screenshotting your level1 and using it for the main menu background to hide the main menu.